# Spring Security: session concurrency control error when login on PC and iPad

Tags: spring-security

My web application uses Spring Security for session management and I set concurrency control max-sessions = 1 as below:

```
<session-management>
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login" />
</session-management>
```

I have 2 test cases as below

- 1) Login same user on 2 browsers (any browser) on PC only.
- 2) Login same user on PC first and then on iPad (Safari).

Expected result is the user on first session will be kicked out. The actual result is the first one is passed but the second one is failed. When I login on iPad, the previous session is not kicked out. Could anyone give me some advice about this? How to fix this case? My iPad is iPad 2.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have not added the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` as described here in the [reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-session-mgmt) and [the FAQ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html#faq-session-listener-missing).

The behaviour you require is the default, but can be overridden by setting the `error-if-maximum-exceeded` attribute to `true`.

Comment: Set 'error-if-maximum-exceeded' means prevent the second login. But this is not the expected result. The expected result is if there is second login then first login must be invalidated. Same as you login yahoo, when you login on this machine and then you login on other machine then the first login is invalidated and kicked out.

Comment: Please re-read my answer. I said the default behaviour is what you require *but can be overridden* by using this attribute (i.e. to get different behaviour). So the configuration you have should already do what you require, provided you add the `HttpSessionEventPublisher`.

Comment: Sorry Luke for my misunderstand your words. HttpSessionEventPublisher is already added in web.xml but it still not work as I expected. Do you have any ideas for this issue?

Comment: Sorry, no. It should work. You'll need to post some extra info to show that the problem is actually due to multiple logins and not something else. What happens if you use different browsers, for example? What is the error you get? What is in the log?

Answer (score 0):

at least in spring 3.2 there is a method maxSessionsPreventsLogin in SessionManagementConfigurer ConcurrencyControlConfigurer class. Try to set it to false, seems you hit its default behaviour at the moment which is:

"If true, prevents a user from authenticating when the
         * {@link #maximumSessions(int)} has been reached"